# How to use 0/10 in cron in a yaml file?

Tags: cron, yaml, circleci

I'm trying to use a cron job referenced in a yaml file part as part of my CircleCI CI system:

I would like a job to run every 10 mins using the `0/10 * * * *` format but I get:

> Config does not conform to schema

So how to use `0/10` in cron in a yaml file?`

Using a valid cron expression:

```
https://crontab.guru/#0/10_*_*_*_*
```

I get

```
Config does not conform to schema: 
{:workflows {:hourly {:triggers [{:schedule {:cron (not (:circleci.specs.cron/posix-expr \"0/10 * * * *\"))}}]}}}
```

I tried various format such as

```
cron: "0/10 * * * *"
cron: 0/10 * * * *
cron: "0\/10 * * * *"
cron: 0\/10 * * * *
```

but none were valid for allowing the slash.

Rest of section for context:

```
  hourly:
    triggers:
      - schedule:
          cron: "0/10 * * * *"
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
                - circleci-project-setup:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#schedule) say

> cron key is defined using POSIX crontab syntax.

The [linked manpage](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/crontab.html) does not specify `/`. It is non-standard and apparently not supported. [Wikipedia says that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

> POSIX does not define a use for slashes; its rationale (commenting on a BSD extension) notes that the definition is based on System V format but does not exclude the possibility of extensions

So you just can't use `/` here.

You can use the equivalent

```
"0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * *"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` operator

So this example works for cron expression:

```
  schedule: >
     '*/3 * * * *'
```